# How to type hint a function, added to class by class decorator in Python

Tags: python-3.x, dynamic, python-decorators, type-hinting, python-typing

I have a class decorator, which adds a few functions and fields to decorated class.

```py
@mydecorator
@dataclass
class A:
    a: str = ""
```

Added (via `setattr()`) is a `.save()` function and a set of info for dataclass fields as a separate dict.

I'd like VScode and mypy to properly recognize that, so that when I use:

```py
a=A()
a.save()
```

or `a.my_fields_dict` those 2 are properly recognized.

Is there any way to do that? Maybe modify class `A` type annotations at runtime?

Comment: Think about what you are saying. You want to change annotations at _runtime_, but the _static_ type checker to know about them? _**Static type checkers don't execute your code, they just read it.**_

Comment: I am having the same issue as you do. Looks like the only solution at the moment (beginning of 2024) is to *both* decorate the class *and* inherit from a mixin that contains the stubs / type annotations for the stuff that the decorator adds...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### TL;DR

What you are trying to do is not possible with the current type system.

---

### 1. Intersection types

If the attributes and methods you are adding to the class via your decorator are static (in the sense that they are not just known at runtime), then what you are describing is effectively the extension of any given class `T` by mixing in a [**protocol**](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/) `P`. That protocol defines the method `save` and so on.

To annotate this you would need an **intersection** of `T & P`. It would look something like this:

```py
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar


T = TypeVar("T")


class P(Protocol):
    @staticmethod
    def bar() -> str: ...


def dec(cls: type[T]) -> type[Intersection[T, P]]:
    setattr(cls, "bar", lambda: "x")
    return cls  # type: ignore[return-value]


@dec
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def foo() -> int:
        return 1
```

You might notice that the import of `Intersection` is conspicuously missing. That is because despite being one of the [most requested features](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213) for the Python type system, it is still missing as of today. There is currently no way to express this concept in Python typing.

---

### 2. Class decorator problems

The only workaround right now is a custom implementation alongside a corresponding plugin for the type checker(s) of your choice. I just stumbled across the [`typing-protocol-intersection`](https://github.com/klausweiss/typing-protocol-intersection) package, which does just that for `mypy`.

If you install that and add `plugins = typing_protocol_intersection.mypy_plugin` to your `mypy` configuration, you could write your code like this:

```py
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar

from typing_protocol_intersection import ProtocolIntersection


T = TypeVar("T")


class P(Protocol):
    @staticmethod
    def bar() -> str: ...


def dec(cls: type[T]) -> type[ProtocolIntersection[T, P]]:
    setattr(cls, "bar", lambda: "x")
    return cls  # type: ignore[return-value]


@dec
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def foo() -> int:
        return 1
```

But here we run into the next problem. Testing this with `reveal_type(A.bar())` via `mypy` will yield the following:

```
error: "Type[A]" has no attribute "bar"  [attr-defined]
note: Revealed type is "Any"
```

Yet if we do this instead:

```py
class A:
    @staticmethod
    def foo() -> int:
        return 1


B = dec(A)

reveal_type(B.bar())
```

we get no complaints from `mypy` and `note: Revealed type is "builtins.str"`. Even though what we did before was equivalent!

This is not a bug of the plugin, but of the `mypy` internals. It is another [long-standing issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3135), that `mypy` does not handle class decorators correctly.

A person in that issue thread even mentioned your use case in conjunction with the desired intersection type.

---

### DIY

In other words, you'll just have to wait until those two holes are patched. Or you can hope that at least the decorator issue by `mypy` is fixed soon-ish and write your own VSCode plugin for intersection types in the meantime. Maybe you can get together with the person behind that `mypy` plugin I mentioned above.

Comment: *This is not a bug of the plugin, but of the mypy internals.* Are you sure? From a quick glance I suppose that adding `get_class_decorator_hook` to `ProtocolIntersectionPlugin` should be sufficient. I'll investigate this and PR if possible, because it looks like a very great thing to have.

Comment: @SUTerliakov I agree, it looks promising. But check the `mypy` issue I linked. And try a simple class decorator without the plugin. It is still broken.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to make `mypy` work on simple class decorator recently, it's still a bug. Maybe hook can cure this... I'll leave a note here upon investigation.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg hmm, interesting, thank you. I already have a Protocol for my added part. Pity there's no intersection yet.