# Type support for dynamically added instance variable

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Because of working a lot with a 3rd party code (Django-ORM), I need to add some variables to the class that are not declared initially.

The simplest Python example would be:

```py
def enrich(obj): 
    obj.c = 5
    return obj
```

It works in Python, but strict type checking fails, and I want to benefit from static type analysis

Full example:

```py
import typing

class A:
    a = 1
    b = 2

class IExt(typing.Protocol):
    c: int

T = typing.TypeVar('T')

def enrich(obj: T) -> IExt | T: 
    typing.cast(IExt, obj).c = 5
    return obj
    
a = A()

print(a.a)  # OK - Works because class is used explicitly
print(enrich(a).c)  # Not OK - Auto-complete works, but type checking shows error
print(enrich(a).b)  # Not OK - Auto-complete works, but type checking shows error
print(enrich(a).x)  # OK - Fails and is expected to fail
```

The error says

```
main.py:21: error: Item "A" of "Union[IExt, A]" has no attribute "c"  [union-attr]
main.py:22: error: Item "IExt" of "Union[IExt, A]" has no attribute "b"  [union-attr]
```

I understand that `Union` is a bit wrong choice here, because it says that variable is either of two types.

What I want to do is to explain type checker that return type extends `Type[T]`

So I'd like to do something like

```
class IExt(typing.Protocol[T], typing.Type[T]):
    c: int = 0
```

But looks like this is not possible. Any ideas for the workaround?

I definitely want to keep it Generic, as `A` here is just example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to type hint a function, added to class by class decorator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75085009/how-to-type-hint-a-function-added-to-class-by-class-decorator-in-python) Intersections is what we want here. Sadly, we don't have them yet.