# How can I enforce a specific output type for a specific input type in Python?

Tags: python, generics, inheritance, python-typing, pydantic

I've been learning how to use Python type hints and there's a particular use case I'm struggling with.

Let's say I have the following Pydantic models:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Horse(BaseModel):
    speed: str
    race_wins: int

class HorseWithHat(Horse):
    hat_color: str

class Snake(BaseModel):
    length: str
    poisonous: bool

class SnakeWithHat(Snake):
    hat_color: str

# Etc.
```

I have various other animal models, each with an associated animal-with-hat model. I now want to implement a function that gives an animal a hat. The type signature would be something like

```py
def give_hat(animal: Animal, hat_color: str) -> AnimalWithHat
```

where `Animal = Union[Horse, Snake, etc.]` and `AnimalWithHat = Union[HorseWithHat, SnakeWithHat, etc.]`. Of course, the issue with this idea is that a `Horse` could go in and a `SnakeWithHat` could come out; I want to enforce consistency.

The other idea I had was to create a `WithHat` generic. The type signature would then be

```py
def give_hat(animal: AnimalTypeVar, hat_color: str) -> WithHat[AnimalTypeVar]
```

with `AnimalTypeVar` being a type variable bound by `Animal = Union[Horse, Snake, etc.]`. This would have the advantage of condensing the repetitious `WithHat` model definitions, however, I haven't been able to figure out a way to define a generic that works in this way (adding a single attribute to an input type).

I'm hoping I'm missing something simple! Any suggestions?

(I am aware I could just combine the non-hat and hat models, making `hat_color` an optional attribute, but in my real project this is finicky to deal with. If possible, I'd like a solution with distinct hatless and hatful models.)

Comment: How many different animals (with potential hats) are we talking here? Single digits? Or potentially hundreds? And are they known by the time you define that function?

Comment: Let's say just a few for now. They'd all have unique attributes, which is why they need distinct models. And yes, they'd all be known at the time I define the function.

Answer (score 2):

The elegant solution *would* of course be [intersection](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213) types, but we don't have them in the Python type system (yet). This was discussed on SO in a few posts already, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75085009/19770795) for example.

Then we'd just define a [protocol](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/) for `WithHat`, define an `Animal` type variable (as you mentioned) for `animal` and define the return type as an intersection of `WithHat` and `Animal`. Alas...

But since you mentioned that there are only a few animal models and you know them all in advance, you could just resort to overloading the signature of `give_hat` with [`typing.overload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload).

```py
from typing import Union, overload
from typing_extensions import TypeAlias


Animal: TypeAlias = Union[Horse, Snake, Cow]
AnimalWithHat: TypeAlias = Union[HorseWithHat, SnakeWithHat, CowWithHat]


@overload
def give_hat(animal: Snake, hat_color: str) -> SnakeWithHat:
    ...


@overload
def give_hat(animal: Cow, hat_color: str) -> CowWithHat:
    ...


@overload
def give_hat(animal: Horse, hat_color: str) -> HorseWithHat:
    ...


def give_hat(animal: Animal, hat_color: str) -> AnimalWithHat:
    return NotImplemented  # actual implementation here
```

This is not as nice and will obviously blow up in your face, if the number of animals starts to increase, but it works.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer. Shame there's no solution. Given how easy to is to enforce T -> T type signatures, I figured T -> map(T) would have some kind of support. In the end I gave up and just used an Animal -> AnimalWithHat signature (with no enforced parity between input and output animal). Not a perfect solution, but I thought the clarity won out over multiple lines of type theory.

Comment: @YotYot5 Well, overloading _is_ a solution. Whether it is viable is of course up to you. I am just saying that as long as the number of distinct signatures is reasonably small, this is a perfectly "normal" solution. Overloads are used everywhere including in the standard library stubs for typeshed. IDEs respect it as well, meaning you do get meaningful auto-suggestions depending on what type you call `give_hat` with.