# Creating child classes with decorators and allow them to have type hints

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-typing, pydantic

I am trying to make a child class through a decorator and also include type hints.
I manage to get type hints of either the parent or the new child methods but not their intersection. I have found similar threads but perhaps this can be solved now with python 3.10+.

Here is an example code:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
import typing as t

T = t.TypeVar('T')


def wrapper(aclass: t.Type[T]) -> t.Type[T]:
    class sqlModel(aclass):
        def get_template_obj(self) -> str:
            return 'example'
    return sqlModel


@wrapper
class myTestModel(BaseModel):
    kingappid: int = 17
    exampleattr: str = 'example'

myTestModel().kingappid # has typehint
myTestModel().exampleattr # has typehint
myTestModel().get_template_obj() # doesn't have typehint

def wrapper2(aclass):
    class sqlModel(aclass):
        def get_template_obj(self) -> str:
            return 'example'
    return sqlModel


@wrapper2
class myTestModel2(BaseModel):
    kingappid: int = 17
    exampleattr: str = 'example'

myTestModel2().kingappid # doesn't have typehint
myTestModel2().exampleattr # doesn't have typehint
myTestModel2().get_template_obj() # has typehint
```

I have tried what was proposed by a couple of threads also using protocols but couldn't manage to make it work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to type hint a function, added to class by class decorator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75085009/how-to-type-hint-a-function-added-to-class-by-class-decorator-in-python/75101725#75101725)

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with the question, but you are using the term _"metaclass"_ wrong in your code. If you inherit from it, it is a **base class** (or parent class). A **metaclass** is the _type_ of a class. E.g. `type` is the metaclass of `object`, but it is not its base/parent class (`object` does not inherit from `type`).

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg the solution in this post, unfortunately, says there is no solution. I changed the name metaclass sorry for that just chose a wrong name.

Comment: Yes, that is the answer to the question. There is no solution in the Python type system for this until we get the intersection type.